# Disable address bar of browser in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-browser, address-bar

I have disabled the android address bar by using the below line of code.

```
  if(isAddressBarEnabled)
        mLayout.findViewById(R.id.address_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        mLayout.findViewById(R.id.address_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Here as i click on a link it would first show the address bar and once the page is loaded it would disappear. I want to disable the address bar while loading also. Is it possible.

Comment: use this in manifest file for activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 0):

From [Android View docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) add this XML code to the address_bar layout.

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: i want to control it. Like i cannot set it as disabled permanently i would handle it, like disable only when required. editing the question accordingly.

Comment: You can always change it. You can't really change it until the program is running, but you can set it up how you wan to before the program starts.

Comment: i want to change it while the program is running dynamically